# ASP.NET MVC Areas with shared layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have defined an area (Admin) in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application, created `_ViewStart.cshtml` in that area and added`Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` to it to have a unified site layout.

I also added the following code to `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Items List", "Index", "Items", new { area = "Admin" }, null)</li>
}
```

The `Admin` area is displayed properly having `_Layout.cshtml` as its layout. But all the navigation links in the page now point to `Admin` subfolder.

For example in my layout I have `<li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home")</li>`,  which points to `Mysite/Home/About`. But after clicking the admin link, the "About Us" link points to `/Admin/Home/About`.

What should I do to have _Layout.cshtml links pointing to the right address?
Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Simply specify a blank area for them if they are to be served from root controllers:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
```

Comment: For @Html.Action(), it throws compilation error when specifying it as blank area as follows '@Html.Action("About", "Home", new { area = "" })'   Need help to resolve this.