# ASP.NET MVC 4 app gives 404, IController error on IIS 7.5/8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, http-status-code-404, iis-8

The last couple of days I've been trying to deploy MVC 4 applications to IIS 7.5 and 8 installations on Server 2008 R2 and 2012, but I'm basically getting the same error every time: 404 and "The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController." On both servers I've made sure that .NET 4, 4.5 and the full MVC 4 stack are installed. The applications run fine on IIS Express in VS 2012.

Things I've tried and results:

- Tried to deploy a clean MVC 3 applicaion: works;
- Tried to deploy a clean MVC 4 application: doesn't work;
- Tried to deploy a clean ASP.NET 4 WebForms application: works (which, I think, rules out the ASP.NET hosting capabilities being a problem);
- Tried to deploy the MVC 4 apps with .NET 4 instead of 4.5: doesn't work (which, I think, rules out the .NET installations being the problem);
- Tried to install hotfix 980368: installer says 'This update is not applicable to your computer', so that is probably already installed;
- Made sure the app pool is on .NET 4.0;
- Made sure all file permissions are setup properly;
- Changed verbs on ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 to *;
- Added the `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` tag.

But still no dice... I've read many SO questions and other websites which resemble the errors I'm getting, and I think I've tried all the tips I've read, but maybe I missed a crucial one.

Has anyone else experienced these problems, that can give me the fix I need?

Comment: This question may provide some insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011026/the-controller-for-path-was-not-found-or-does-not-implement-icontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, as it seems, adding the debug symbols (.pdb) to the bin folder makes the app start working again, even though it was deployed in Release mode. I'll do some research as to why this happens.

Edit: the answer can be found here: [Removing .pdb from ASP.NET app on IIS breaks application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664008/removing-pdb-from-asp-net-app-on-iis-breaks-application/15718353#15718353)