# Call static function in view mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, layout

i'm working on a mvc project and i want to display a sponsorimage on each page.

But i'm having difficulties with showing them into the shared layout page that is rendered on with each view.

I've created a function in my Domain service class where i search the student's school, because the school is linked to a country, not the student.
When i got that countryId, i search through the countries of each Advert where the countryId is equal to the school's countryId. When that's the case, i look for the sponsor of that particular advert, put them into a SponsorList, select a random sponsor from that SponsorList and return the SponsorCompany (because i renamed each sponsorimage to the companyname).

Now i want to call that function into the shared layout, so every time the pages renders, a random sponsorimage is showed for that particular student. But i dont know how to call that function because shared layout has no controller class.

```
    public String advertsForCountry()
{
    String studentSchool = finder.getLoggedStudent().SchoolId;
    int studentCountry = db.Schools.Find(studentSchool).CountryId;

    List<Sponsor> sponsorsForStudent = new List<Sponsor>();
    List<Advert> adverts = db.Adverts.ToList();
    foreach(Advert adv in adverts)
    {
        foreach(Country cntry in adv.Countries)
        {
            if(cntry.CountryId == studentCountry)
            {
                sponsorsForStudent.Add(adv.Sponsor);
            }
        }
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomSP = random.Next(0, sponsorsForStudent.Count()-1);
    string sponsorAdvert = sponsorsForStudent.ElementAt(randomSP).SponsorCompany;
    return sponsorAdvert;       
}
```

Sorry English is not my native language.

Comment: Consider making a child action.

Comment: My suggestion would to forget about the `static method` because it's not a correct `MVC` pattern the logic of business model should not be in a `View`.
Create a `ViewModel` then return a simple `PartialView` bound to that `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand upon @SLaks suggestion;

Create an action that is marked with a `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` (this prevents it from being called via a regular HTTP request). Here's an example from my website:

```
[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult RandomQuote()
{
    var model = _services.GetRandomQuote();

    return PartialView("_QuoteOfTheMomentWidget", model);
}
```

This child action gets called in the `_Layout` via a simple `@Html.Action("randomquote")`.

Comment: But in which controller you put the code? Because _Layout.cshtml has no controller.

Comment: @Gijs Any controller works. For instance, the one I posted assumes the action is defined in the Home controller, and that a `_QuoteOfTheMoment.cshtml` view exists in either the `home` or `shared` folder. If it was in, say, `WidgetsController`, the call gets adjusted to `@Html.Action("randomquote", "widgets")`.

Comment: i'm implementing your solution but get the error
'{"The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController."}' I thought i found the solution here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011026/the-controller-for-path-was-not-found-or-does-not-implement-icontroller
But i'm not working with these area's, this funtion has to work for everyone.

Comment: @Gijs Post what you're trying to use - it sounds like you're using the incorrect syntax for the view parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller action that returns a partial view.

```
public PartialViewResult SponsoredAdvert()
{
    var model = new SponsoredAdverModel();
    model.AdvertText = _domainService.advertsForCountry();
    return PartialView("myView", model);
}
```

Place the method in a suitable controller (`HomeController` would make sense given that this is for your Layout.cshtml) and use `RenderAction` in your view:

```
@Html.RenderAction("MyAction", "MyController")
```

As you can see, `RenderAction` allows you to *specify* the controller, which means that you can use this within your Layout.cshtml even though it, in itself, is not associated with a specific controller.

Comment: I'm not calling the method in the homecontroller view, but in the shared _layout.cshtm view. This contains my navigation bar etc and has no controller. If i put it in the homecontroller, this wil only be working on the homepage.

Comment: No, it won't. As I described in my answer, `RenderAction` takes a `controller` parameter which allows you to specify which controller class contains the action method `MyAction`. You can use it to render PartialViewResults from any controller into any view - including from Layout.cshtml.