# Not Loading Partial View in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In my `_Layout.cshtml` view I have

```
@using SiteNET.Utilities
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>"SomeTitle"</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
          sizes="256x256"
          href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/SiteRetro256.png")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon"
          href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Icons/SiteRetro.ico")">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="navbar-toggle"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    </button>
                    @Html.ActionLink(SiteNET.Utilities.Constants.Site,
                        "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("Home")">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")
                        </li>
                        <li class="@Url.MakeActive("Index", "Contacts")">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "Index", "Contacts")
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    @Html.Action("_LoginPartial", "Account") <- THIS LINE
                </div>
            </div> <!--container-fluid-->
        </div> <!--navbar-->
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My aim is be able to load a view model into my `_LoginPartial` view. So I have added the following to my `AccountController` class

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _LoginPartial()
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    ManageUserViewModel model = null;
    string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId() ?? String.Empty;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
    {
        user = UserManager.FindById(userID);
        model = new ManageUserViewModel();
        model.IsAdmin = user.IsAdmin;
    }
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

But this does not call this method from

```
@Html.Action("_LoginPartial", "Account")`
```

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14011583/626442) and have swapped the

```
@Html.Action("_LoginPartial", "Account")
```

to

```
@Html.Action("_LoginPartial", "Account", new { area = "" })
```

as the controller is not in the "Shared" folder. I have also tried

```
@Html.Action("_LoginPartial", "Account", new { area = "Controllers" })`
```

but I am just getting a browser error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time.

---

*Edit. following @markpSmith's suggestion, I have attempted to use*

```
 @{ Html.RenderAction("_LoginPartial", "Account"); }
```

_but this give the same error. _

Comment: Have you tried `Html.RenderAction`?

Comment: No, I will try this now. Thanks. Downvoter, this is _not_ outside of the scope of the forum. The question is well posed and has all of the required info...

Comment: Agree with above - a downvote is pointless without feedback so have cancelled it out with an upvote.

Comment: Cheers. I am just looking into how to use the `RenderAction`. Thanks again...

Comment: This gives the same error in the browser without an exception...

Comment: Are you using Areas?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. I tried adding `new { area = "" }` as the third parameter, but this did not help me. This is a very basic application and I am a novice.

Comment: Do you get the error regardless of whether the model is null or not?

Comment: Yeas, when I force the view model to be non-null, the same browser error occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")`

You don't need to specify action in Controller as you can access User.Identity in View so update _LoginPartial with User.Identity instead of Model.

Comment: But then in the view I will have to get the user like `user = UserManager.FindById(userID)` so will have to intantiate the `UserManager` is this okay to do?

Comment: You can check if logged in user is Admin using User.IsInRole("Admin") code so I think you don't need to user info from UserManager. Is it making sense?

Comment: Kind of, but I am not using Roles (this may be deemed bad!). The reason is that the application is very simple and there will be only one Admin user. So i have stored a field called `IsAdmin` in the user database. All users are created `IsAdmin=false` except a single user called `Administrator` which has `IsAdmin =true` set when the database is first created. I am taking your advice though and checking the `User.IsAdmin` in the view...

Comment: I would suggest instead on invoking Action for this single reason you can create BaseController and override OnActionExecuting and set ViewBag.IsAdmin true or false as per your conditions. And inherit all your controllers from BaseController.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see if you have attempted the:

```
@Html.RenderPartial()
```

ActionMethod (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(v=vs.118).aspx))

making yours look similar to:

## View:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_LoginPartial","Account")
```

## Controller:

(within AccountController)

```
public ActionResult _LoginPartial()
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    ManageUserViewModel model = null;
    string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId() ?? String.Empty;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
    {
        user = UserManager.FindById(userID);
        model = new ManageUserViewModel();
        model.IsAdmin = user.IsAdmin;
    }
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Other than that, I would suggest removing the underscore and see if you can run it instead (since it is a partial view, I don't ***think*** it will be navigateable anyway)

Comment: @Killercam It's what I use to open Partial views, anyway. I've never heard of/used {areas =...} ever so not entirely sure that's required.

Comment: One thing is that `RenderPartial` returns void, so you can just put it "in place of" this `@Html.Action` method...