# How to fix the exception: 'The controller for path '/null' was not found or does not implement IController.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'v been monitoring my mvc 5 web application that is deployed on azure using application insights and once in a while I get this Exception: 'The controller for path '/null' was not found or does not implement IController.'

When I check the telemetry before this request, I see

1. GET Home/Index
2. GET null/Index
3. The controller for path '/null' was not found or does not implement IController.

I checked my Index.cshtml for any possible erroneous code and could only narrow down to this piece of line:

```
@Html.Action("TestMethod", "Home", Model)
```

So, is there a way to avoid this exception?

EDIT: I looked here: [The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011026/the-controller-for-path-was-not-found-or-does-not-implement-icontroller) but here the answers are specific to 'Areas' in MVC whereas there aren't any areas in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The controller for path was not found or does not implement IController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011026/the-controller-for-path-was-not-found-or-does-not-implement-icontroller)

Comment: @Html.Action("TestMethod", "Home", Model) for /home/testmethod, can you check somewhere you build url?